# How do I make my navbar toggle button responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I am trying to make my navbar toggle button responsive, when shrinking the screen size, both the log in and sign up are responsive and move inward towards the other navbar elements until a certain breakpoint, then they disappear, however when I make them disappear and have my navbar toggle appear, my navbar toggle does not stay responsive or keep the same distance that the log in and sign in elements did from the logo (put your own logo as a place holder) I want my navbar toggle to function the same way as the the log in and sign up elements when shrinking the screen. I tried putting the toggle button inside the same div as the log in and sign up elements but when I made the div disappear the toggle button would not appear in their place, i also tried making a separate div for the toggle button (as shown in the code snippet) and tried to give it display: flex and that also did nothing.

```
<>
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/decexodus/pen/ExRJYeK

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0%;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.left-elements {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  padding-inline-start: 1.5em;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

.right-elements {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-inline-end: 4em;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

.logo {
  padding-inline-start: 0.5em;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 15rem;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  body {
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
  }
  .left-elements {
    display: none;
  }
  .right-elements {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href=""><img class="logo" src="./images/Donation_Hub-3-2-removebg-preview.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="left-elements">
    <a href="">About</a>
    <a href="">Pricing</a>
    <a href="">Integrations</a>
    <a href="">Support</a>
  </div>
  <div class="right-elements">
    <a href="">Log In</a>
    <a href=""><button class="sign-up">Sign Up</button></a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-toggle">
    <a href="">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-list" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to justify the items in your navbar and give margin to the toggle.

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0%;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    align-items: center;
    height: 5rem;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    /* Added this */
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-elements {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1.5rem;
    padding-inline-start: 1.5em;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
.right-elements {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-inline-end: 4em;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}

.logo {
    padding-inline-start: 0.5em;
    height: 3rem;
    width: 15rem;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
    body {
        background-color: rebeccapurple;
    }

    .left-elements {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .right-elements {
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar-toggle {
        display: flex;
        /* same value as padding in .right-elements */
        margin-right: 4em;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href=""><img class="logo" src="./images/Donation_Hub-3-2-removebg-preview.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="left-elements">
    <a href="">About</a>
    <a href="">Pricing</a>
    <a href="">Integrations</a>
    <a href="">Support</a>
  </div>
  <div class="right-elements">
    <a href="">Log In</a>
    <a href=""><button class="sign-up">Sign Up</button></a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-toggle">
    <a href="#">
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-list" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```